# Antiderivative of $\frac{x^n \ln(a x^2+b x)}{(a x^2+b x)^m}$

Tags: indefinite-integrals

I need help with the integral.

\begin{equation}
I_{n,m}(a,b)=\int dx \frac{x^n \ln(a x^2+b x)}{(a x^2+b x)^m}\,,\enspace\enspace \begin{array}{rcl}n,m &=& {1,2,3,\ldots},\enspace (n\geq m)\\ a, b&\neq&0 \end{array}  
\end{equation}

I would like to get a result that is some kind of terminating series involving a polynomial of $x$ and their logarithms.

I started by splitting the logarithm and factoring out an $x$ from the denominator:

\begin{equation}
I_{n,m}(a,b) = \int dx \frac{x^{n-m}\ln(x)}{(a x+b)^m} + \int dx \frac{x^{n-m}\ln(a x+ b)}{(a x+b)^m}
\end{equation}

But, now I'm stuck.  I don't know how to calculate either of these integrals.

Comment: Have you tried to integrate simple cases (like $m, n = 1, 2$)?

Comment: @rubik ooh.. I think it is best to make a substitution: $y=(ax+b)$.. still working on it...

Comment: @rubik Ok, I just realized that this integral is not suitable as a stackexchange question since it is just a laborious task with not too much insight.  Can you initiate a vote to close?

Comment: Well I think that it's an interesting problem, and you could just answer with a pointer to the solution (just a sketch of it). You can accept your own answer and [it's encouraged too](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer).